# How a header file knows where the implementation of a function prototype is?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, header-files

I have the following files:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_math.h"

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 5;
    add(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

**my_math.h**

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

**my_math.c**

```
#include "my_math.h"
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I know that using `#include "my_math.h"` copies the content of my_math.h file within the file where it is called. However, how does main.c file where the implementation of add() function is?
At the beginning I thought that **my_math.h** and **my_math.c** should match the name, but not the extension, but I have changed the name from my_math.c to **my_matho.c** and everything is working as previously, so how the heck C know where the implementation of the function is?

I am using the following command to compile:

```
gcc -g -O0 -Wall main.c my_math.c -o main
```

One more question is it the same the previous command than:

```
gcc -g -O0 -Wall my_math.c main.c -o main
```

so it means that the order in which I indicate the files to be compiled does not matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different stages, compilation and linking.

- During compilation, compiler only needs to know the *prototype* of the function.
- During linking, the object files are actually linked together.

So, during compilation, the *where* part is not required. However, while linking, the function should be present in one of the object files which are being linked together.

To elaborate, that is why we see that, even with a missing header file (forward declaration of a function) but with all required object files, the compilation and linking can happen (with warnings, obviously) (and linker can actually find and link the required function implementation), but even if with the proper header file, if you don't supply the required object file which contains the actual definition, the linker will <del>scream at you</del> throw error.

Comment: Oh this is a really good and clear explanation. I thought that while compiling the where mattered. Thank you.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What do you mean by forward declaration of a function?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf [hope this helps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration). basically what you've done in `my_math.h`. :)

Answer (score 5):

The compiler does not know. The linker does.

Each source file is compiled to a object file:

main.c becomes main.o and my_math.c becomes my_math.o - for example.

When compiling `main.c` The function prototype in `my_math.h`, tells the compiler that there will be a function `int add(int a, int b);` which it can call but it has no extra knowledge about this function.

When the linker links main.o and my_math.o into the executable it performs the necessary relocation.